# Basic Zend application - URL does not route correctly

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I am new to Zend and trying to create my first Zend application.  I used zf.sh to create my project.  I left everything untouched and modified just the indexAction method in the default IndexController.php to assign some data to the view.

I go to the URL mydomain/myapp/ and the view loads successfully.  However, I go to mydomain/myapp/index and I get a page not found.  I created another method in IndexController.php named testAction.  I try to get to via mydomain/myapp/index/test, and I also get a page not found.

Since I left all the configuration as is (generated by zf.sh), I figured this all should just work right out of the box, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: I assume you're using Zend Framework 1. What web server are you using? Apache? What OS?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated earlier - I am using ZF1.8, Apache 2.2, on a Linux server.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using for this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this might be an issue with the vhost settings for your new project.

There is some information in the quickstart regarding [creating a virtual host](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost). The important things to note are the `Document Root` and the `Directory` section should have the same path, which points to the `public` folder of your project. Also the `AllowOverride All` directive is important, because it allows the `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory to set up the rewrite rules.

If you used `zf.sh` to create your project, then you should see a file in the `docs` dir called `README.txt`. This file will contain some text, as well as an example vhosts configuration - which should already contain the correct configurations to get you started. You can simply cut and paste the `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` section from this file into a vhost file (You'll need to work out the correct way to do this for your particular operating system) and it should work as it is.

One thing I seem to remember for Ubuntu is that files in the `sites-available` directory *shouldn't* end in a `.conf` or they *won't* be parsed (YMMV). You must also remember to enable the vhost (`sudo a2ensite <The name of your vhost>` for Ubuntu) and reload the apache configs (`sudo apache2 reload` for Ubuntu).

Also note that that `zf.sh` will have created a .htaccess file in your project's `public` directory. You shouldn't need to touch this file, but make sure that it's there. It contains the rewrite rules that tell apache to send all the requests for your application through `index.php` for routing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Luke Mills thanks for your answer.  I set up the virtual host as recommended and it's still isn't working properly.  I can now access the default controller and its actions via the URLs: mydomain/index, mydomain/index/index, and mydomain/index/test (so I am a bit better off than before).  However, when I created a new controller called TestController, I get a page not found (displayed by the generated ErrorController.php).  Also got a bit further in than previously since the error was not handle by the error controller before.  Could this also have something to do with the apache config?

Comment: It sounds like this is an unrelated problem. It would probably be best to start a new question that gives the specific details of the new problem, and include a copy of you TestController code.

Comment: D'oh.  Turned out the permission was not set properly on my new controller and apache was unable to access it.  Thanks for your help.  This answer solved my original issue.